# MongoDocument Object only gets partially populated when querying

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I have a collection of users that I'm trying to read from the database, but for some reason some strange behavior takes place that I can't really figure out. Hopefully, somebody can suggest or help me find the root of this problem.

So basically, what happens is that whenever I call this code in my HomeController.cs:

```
var users = await _database.GetCollection<User>("ApplicationUsers").FindAsync(_ => true);
var userList = users.ToList();
```

it only populates userList partially, meaning only the ID and ConcurrencyStamp properties get filled, but the other properties always end up being null (as seen in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hheFl.png)

But whenever I add this line right after the database connection initialization in the Startup.cs:

```
database.GetCollection<User>("ApplicationUsers");
```

Then suddenly userList does get populated with all the other information (as seen in            https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIdeq.png)

So in order for it to work, I have to get the collection right after the connection gets initialized which I'm not really fond of, because I don't have to do this for other collections. So my mongo connection code would have to look like this in the Startup.cs:

```
var mongoUrl = new MongoUrl(config.GetSection("DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString").Value);

var mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(mongoUrl);
mongoClientSettings.ClusterConfigurator = cb => ConfigureCluster(cb);

var client = new MongoClient(mongoClientSettings);
var database = client.GetDatabase(config.GetSection("DatabaseSettings:DatabaseName").Value);
database.GetCollection<User>("ApplicationUsers"); // TODO: This is needed just to let Mongo Driver know to which class to deserialize this collection

services.AddSingleton<IMongoDatabase>(database);

var pack = new ConventionPack()
{
    new CamelCaseElementNameConvention(),
    new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true),
    new DictionaryRepresentationConvention(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfArrays)
};

ConventionRegistry.Register("DatabaseConventions", pack, t => true);
```

I'm guessing something happens between the execution of Startup.cs and HomeController.cs that causes the deserialization to mess up?

**Update:**

The same behavior seems to happen on a clean project, the only nuget packages I installed are the official mongodb driver and AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo by Matteo Fabbri. This strange deserialize behavior does not happen when I use getCollection for other classes. The problem lies with ApplicationUser which extends from MongoUser (a class made available by the AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo library)

**Update 2:**

Turns out that MongoUser class from the AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo library is allergic to the ConventionPack that was registered. I tested this by getting the collection before and after the registration of the database conventions. Now finding a proper solution for this.

**Update 3:**

Also I found out that documents are saved with properties named in Upper Camel Case, which could be the cause for mongodb driver's confusion. It seems that the conventions set to save them in CamelCase is being ignored for this particular class (ApplicationUser).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. The issue was the order of code execution. The convention pack was registered after MongoIdentity and the database was initialized. During the initialization of MongoIdentity and the Database, the ApplicationUser was configured to not have the CamelCaseElementNameConvention in the pack, which led to the class being saved in UpperCamelCase and therefore cause confusion when retrieving the collection when the registered ConventionPack was active.

For whoever struggles with strange behavior where you may think your code should work, remember that the order of code execution is very important and could very well be the cause of the behavior. Good luck to y'all!